# Proving that the value of the integral doesn't depend on the surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if we have the vector field $v : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given in spherical coordinates by:

$$v(\rho, \theta, \phi)=\frac{1}{\rho^2}\hat{\rho}$$

Where $\hat{\rho}$ is the outward unit vector, then the integral of this field over any surface should be $4\pi$. I don't know if it's really true, but it *seems* true for me. I'm trying to prove or give a counterexample, but I didn't find a proof neither a counterexample.

Can someone give a hint on how to get started with this problem ? Thanks very much for your help!

**Edit:** I'm thinking on a closed surface enclosing the origin. I *know* that the field is not defined there, and that is the reason I'm trying to prove that independent of the closed surface that encloses the origin the integral should be $4\pi$. Sorry if I forgot to mention this before.

Comment: So you can compute this thing on the sphere directly without resorting to Divergence theorem. For any surface, think of it as the outer boundary of a solid. I am with holding one more hint unless you really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be a "closed surface enclosing the origin" $O$, oriented outwards. Such an $S$ bounds a certain "three-dimensional body" $B$ which contains  $O$. This idea includes, e.g. the boundary $\partial C$ of the cube $C:=[-1,1]^3$. Then there will be an $\epsilon>0$ such that all points of $S$ 
have a distance $>\epsilon$ from $O$. Denote by $B_\epsilon$ the open ball with radius $\epsilon$ and center $O$.

Now we apply Gauss' theorem to the body $B':=B\setminus B_\epsilon$. The set $B'$, whose  boundary is given by $\partial B'=S-\partial B_\epsilon\ $, no longer contains $O$. Therefore it is allowed to apply Gauss' theorem to $B'$ and ${\bf v}$. We obtain
$$\int\nolimits_S {\bf v}\cdot\vec{d\omega}-\int\nolimits_{\partial B_\epsilon} {\bf v}\cdot\vec{d\omega}=\int\nolimits_{\partial B'} {\bf v}\cdot\vec{d\omega}=\int\nolimits_{B'}{\rm div}({\bf v})\ {\rm dvol}=0\ ,$$
which implies
$$\int\nolimits_S {\bf v}\cdot\vec{d\omega}=\int\nolimits_{\partial B_\epsilon} {\bf v}\cdot\vec{d\omega}=\int\nolimits_{\partial B_\epsilon} {1\over\epsilon^2}\ {\rm d}\omega=\ \omega(\partial B_\epsilon)\ {1\over\epsilon^2}=4\pi\ .$$

Comment: Why do you have $\mathrm{div}(v) = 0$? In order to know this, you have to extend $\hat \rho$ to $B$.

Comment: @gerw No you don't.  The integral is taken over $ B'$, and the Gauss theorem is being applied to the integral taken over $ B'$, not $ B $.

Comment: Ok, this was a typo. You have to extend $\hat\rho$ to B'.

Comment: I think I've understood what he did. $B'$ doesn't contain the origin, so in $B'$ the divergence is zero and the theorem really holds. That's the key to the proof right ? We simply "cut off" where there's the problem, and then we use the relations involving the integrals over the sets to show what's desired. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I think, there are some issues left with this answer. For example, let $B_1$ be a ball which contains the origin. Then, the surface integral is $4 \, \pi$. Now, let $B_2 \subset B_1$ be another ball which does not contain the origin. Then, the surface integral over $B_1 \setminus B_2$ is also $4 \, \pi$, but it should be larger than the surface integral over $B_1$, because its surface is a superset of the surface of $B_1$. This is a contradiction. Hence, Christians answer could not be right. The reason is, that $\mathrm{div}(v)$ may not hold in $B'$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: But you have proven that the flow integral over every surface containing the origin is $4 \, \pi$. Hence, also the flow integral over $\partial(B_1 \setminus B_2)$ is $4 \, \pi$ and not zero. This contradicts your comment.

Comment: @gerw: Sorry for the slip. I have deleted my last comment. The surface integral over $\partial(B_1\setminus B_2)$ is still $4\pi$, because the integral over $\partial B_2$ is zero.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: But the surface integral over $\partial B_2$ has to be positive, since the integrand is $v \, \hat\rho = 1/r^2 > 0$ and the surface has positive measure.

Comment: @gerw: **No**. On the part of $\partial B_2$ that is visible from the origin one has ${\bf v}\cdot \vec{d\omega}<0$. – This is my last word on this matter.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Ok, here is my last word: This is *not* true. Since $\vec{d\omega} = \hat\rho \, dA$, you have $v \cdot \vec{d\omega} = r^{-2} \, dA$. Hence, the integrand on $\partial B_2$ is strictly positive. (Note that the direction of $\vec{d\omega}$ has nothing to do with the location of the origin).

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Now I've realized what's going on here. By $\hat\rho$ you didn't denote the _outer normal vector_ (of the surface) as written by the OP, but the unit vector pointing away from the origin. You are totally right! Sorry for the inconvinience.